# Average length of uninterrupted play in basketball

Tags: statistics, basketball, training

I am wondering, if there are any statistics about the average time a basketball game is "live", that means there is no whistle by the referee (dead ball) and no chance for the players to rest (even just for a few seconds).

For example, team A is on offense for 20 seconds, shoots and gets an offensive rebound. Team A then continues to play for another 24 seconds and scores. Team B takes the ball in at the baseline and their point guard is fouled 12 seconds later. This sums up to 56 seconds of play time.

My question is how long is this time span **on average**. From a conditioning perspective, what is the average length of stress players need to prepare their bodies for.

I am sure some leagues (or at least some teams) have stats about this but I have no idea what to search for.

Comment: Are you asking for any league in particular? I only ask because I feel it would be extraneous and unrealistic to compile data from every major basketball league. So are you asking about FIBA or the NBA or some other league?

Comment: I'm asking for FIBA but, honestly, any set of data would be interesting and helpful. I don't think it would differ all that much on the top level (NBA or FIBA). College basketball would be different as they use a 30-second shot clock (but even that data could give some insight if it existed).